# How to route nav tab with parameters in angular?

Tags: angular

Let's say I'm at the Tab1 with the parameter id=1. Concretely the resulting url is http://localhost:4200/project/tab1;id=1. Now I click Tab2 and the url changes to  http://localhost:4200/project/tab2. Is there a way to route the id too so that I get http://localhost:4200/project/tab2;id=1?

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qzwzju

```
<nav mat-tab-nav-bar [backgroundColor]="'primary'">
    <div mat-tab-link *ngFor="let link of navTabs" [routerLink]="link.link" routerLinkActive #rla="routerLinkActive"
      [active]="rla.isActive">
      {{link.label}}
    </div>
</nav>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

```
navTabs: NavTab[];

activeLinkIndex: number = -1;

constructor(private router: Router, private route: ActivatedRoute) {
  this.navTabs = [
    { label: 'Tab1', link: './tab1', index: 0 },
    { label: 'Tab2', link: './tab2', index: 1 },
    { label: 'Tab3', link: './tab3', index: 2 },
  ];
}

ngOnInit(): void {   
  this.router.events.subscribe((res) => {
    this.activeLinkIndex = this.navTabs.indexOf(this.navTabs.find((tab: NavTab) => tab.link === '.' + this.router.url));
  });
}
```

```
export const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'tab1', component: Tab1Component },
  { path: 'tab2', component: Tab2Component },
  { path: 'tab3', component: Tab3Component },
];
```

Comment: can you create a demo on stackblitz ??

Comment: Here is a demo but somehow it doesn't work on stackblitz. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qzwzju

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by setting the `state` on the router.

Example: (`this.router` is `Router`)

```
// In TypeScript
this.router.navigate(['/tab1'], {state: {something: 1}});
```

or

```
// In HTML
<a [routerLink]=”/tab1” [state]=”{ something: 1}”>Go to B</a>
```

Then, in your target component, you can retrieve the value from the `state` by:

```
this.router.getCurrentNavigation().extras.state.something
```

You may need to subscribe to the router events and wait for `NavigationEnd` if you find it too noisy.

Another option is to just grab it from `history.state.data`. I'd argue that this isn't "the angular way" but it works.

Other options are:

- use a NavigationResolver
- Implement a State Machine like NgRx
- Create a Service and use an `EventEmitter` to broadcast the `id` to any other components that might want to know about it.

Comment: Where should I use this.router.navigate? The nav tabs don't use this to navigate to the specifc tab url. Can you show a stackblitz demo?

Comment: Then I would use the `[routerLink]` with the `[state]` directives in your html template. Whether you do it in TypeScript or within your HTML makes no differnce.